# NestJS Angular Error: invalid input syntax for integer: "undefined"

Tags: angular, postgresql, forms, sequelize.js, nestjs

Im new to Nest JS and Angular and I'm trying to create an PUT form, however I'm getting the error: Error: invalid input syntax for integer: "undefined". Im using Sequelize and Postgresql as database.
My GET and DELETE requests works fine, but not PUT. Interesting part, that in Postman my PUT requests works without any problem. CORS enabled.

My error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "title", "content", "image", "category", "userId", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "articles" AS "Article" WHERE "Article"."id" = 'undefined';
[Nest] 13792  - 17.01.2024, 19:24:13   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] неприпустимий синтаксис для типу integer: "undefined"
Error: 
    at Query.run (C:\Projects\mythology-application\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\postgres\query.js:76:25)
    at C:\Projects\mythology-application\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:650:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at PostgresQueryInterface.select (C:\Projects\mythology-application\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:1001:12)
    at Function.findAll (C:\Projects\mythology-application\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1824:21)
    at Function.findOne (C:\Projects\mythology-application\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1998:12)
    at ArticlesService.updateArticle (C:\Projects\mythology-application\src\articles\articles.service.ts:64:20)
    at C:\Projects\mythology-application\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at C:\Projects\mythology-application\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Here is my back-end:

**articles.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Article } from './schema/articles.schema';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { CreateArticleDto } from './dto/create-article.dto';
import { FilesService } from 'src/files/files.service';
import { Repository } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { UpdateArticleDto } from './dto/update-article.dto';

@Injectable()
export class ArticlesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Article) private articleRepository: Repository<Article>,
    private fileService: FilesService,
  ) {}

  async create(dto: CreateArticleDto, image: any) {
    const fileName = await this.fileService.createFile(image);
    const post = await this.articleRepository.create({
      ...dto,
      image: fileName,
    });
    return post;
  }

  async getArticleById(id: string) {
    const article = await this.articleRepository.findOne({
      where: { id },
      include: { all: true },
    });

    return article;
  }

  async getAllArticles() {
    const article = await this.articleRepository.findAll({
      include: { all: true },
    });
    return article;
  }

  async updateArticle(
    id: number,
    updateDTO: UpdateArticleDto,
  ): Promise<Article> {
    const record = await this.articleRepository.findOne({
      where: { id },
    });

    if (!record) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Record with ID ${id} not found`);
    }

    Object.assign(record, updateDTO);

    return await record.save();
  }

  async deleteArticle(id: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.articleRepository.destroy({
      where: { id },
    });
    console.log('Article was Deleted');
  }
}
```

**articles.controllers.ts**

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Delete,
  Get,
  Param,
  Post,
  Put,
  UploadedFile,
  UseGuards,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ArticlesService } from './articles.service';
import { CreateArticleDto } from './dto/create-article.dto';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Roles } from 'src/auth/decorator/roles-auth.decorator';
import { RolesGuard } from 'src/auth/guards/roles.guard';
import { UpdateArticleDto } from './dto/update-article.dto';

@Controller('articles')
export class ArticlesController {
  constructor(private articleService: ArticlesService) {}

  @Roles('admin')
  @UseGuards(RolesGuard)
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image'))
  createArticle(@Body() dto: CreateArticleDto, @UploadedFile() image) {
    return this.articleService.create(dto, image);
  }

  @Get(':id')
  async getArticle(
    @Param('id')
    id: string,
  ) {
    return this.articleService.getArticleById(id);
  }

  @Get()
  getAll() {
    return this.articleService.getAllArticles();
  }

  @Put(':id')
  updateArticle(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() updateDTO: UpdateArticleDto) {
    return this.articleService.updateArticle(id, updateDTO);
  }

  @Roles('admin')
  @UseGuards(RolesGuard)
  @Delete(':id')
  deleteArticle(@Param('id') id: number) {
    return this.articleService.deleteArticle(+id);
  }
}
```

**update-article.dto.ts -** if needed

```
export class UpdateArticleDto {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly content: string;
  readonly category: string;
  readonly image: string;
}
```

And here is my Angular Front-end:

**services.service.ts -** there are almost all of my requests, anyway

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { ArticleInterface } from './interfaces/article.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServicesService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getArticles() {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:1268/articles');
  }

  getArticleDetails(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:1268/articles/' + id);
  }

  deleteArticle(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.delete('http://localhost:1268/articles/' + id);
  }

  update(id: number, updateDTO: ArticleInterface): Observable<any> {
    const url = `http://localhost:1268/articles/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.put(url, updateDTO);
  }

  getCalendar() {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:1268/calendar');
  }

  getCalendarDetails(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:1268/calendar/' + id);
  }
}
```

**article-details.component.ts -** i have DialogElementsExampleDialog as popup PUT form

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticleDetailsInterface } from './article-details.interface';
import { ServicesService } from '../services.service';

import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { ArticleInterface } from '../interfaces/article.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-details',
  templateUrl: './article-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-details.component.scss'],
})
export class ArticleDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string | undefined | null;
  data: undefined | ArticleDetailsInterface;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private readonly articleDetailsService: ServicesService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = params.get('id');

      if (this.id) {
        this.articleDetailsService
          .getArticleDetails(this.id)
          .subscribe((articleData) => {
            this.data = articleData;
            console.log(this.data);
          });
      }
    });
  }

  delete(id: string): void {
    this.articleDetailsService.deleteArticle(id).subscribe();
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogElementsExampleDialog);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-elements-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-elements-example-dialog.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
})
export class DialogElementsExampleDialog implements OnInit {
  updateForm: FormGroup;
  id: number;

  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private readonly articleDetailsService: ServicesService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
      title: '',
      content: '',
      category: '',
      image: '',
    });
  }

  updateModel(): void {
    const updateDto: ArticleInterface = this.updateForm.value;
    this.articleDetailsService.update(this.id, updateDto).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('Update successful', response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error updating', error);
      },
    );
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }
}
```

**dialog-elements-example-dialog.html**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="updateModel()">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" formControlName="title" required />

    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <input type="text" id="content" formControlName="content" required />

    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <input type="text" id="category" formControlName="category" required />

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="updateForm.invalid">Update Model</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close (click)="closeDialog()">Close</button>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWjUQ.png)

Here is my Postman PUT request that works perfecty fine:

Comment: Where does `this.id` get set in the `DialogElementsExampleDialog`?